# Cloud Dataflow GlobalWindow trigger ignored

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql, apache-beam, spotify-scio

Using the AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast trigger does not work when run using the Dataflow runner, but works correctly when run locally.  When run on Dataflow, it produces only a single pane.

The goals is to extract data from Cloud SQL, transform and write into Cloud Storage.  However, there is too much data to keep in memory, so it needs to be split up and written to Cloud Storage in chunks.  That's what I hoped this would do.

The complete code is:

```
      val pipe = sc.jdbcSelect(getReadOptions(connOptions, stmt))
        .applyTransform(ParDo.of(new Translator()))
        .map(row => row.mkString("|"))
        // produce one global window with one pane per ~500 records
        .withGlobalWindow(WindowOptions(
          trigger = Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(500)),
          accumulationMode = AccumulationMode.DISCARDING_FIRED_PANES
        ))

      val out = TextIO
        .write()
        .to("gs://test-bucket/staging")
        .withSuffix(".txt")
        .withNumShards(1)
        .withShardNameTemplate("-P-S")
        .withWindowedWrites() // gets us one file per window & pane
      pipe.saveAsCustomOutput("writer",out)
```

I think the root of the problem may be that the `JdbcIO` class is implemented as a `PTransform<PBegin,PCollection>` and a single call to processElement outputs the entire SQL query result:

```
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) throws Exception {
      try (PreparedStatement statement =
          connection.prepareStatement(
              query.get(), ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)) {
        statement.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
        parameterSetter.setParameters(context.element(), statement);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
          while (resultSet.next()) {
            context.output(rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet));
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I had two problems to resolve:
1. The process would run out of memory, and 2. the data was written to a single file.

There is no way to work around problem 1 with Beam's JdbcIO and Cloud SQL because of the way it uses the MySQL driver.  The driver itself loads the entire result within a single call to `executeStatement`.  There is a way to get the driver to stream results, but I had to implement my own code to do that.  Specifically, I implemented a BoundedSource for JDBC.

For the second problem, I used the row number to set the timestamp of each element.  That allows me to explicitly control how many rows are in each window using `FixedWindows`.

Answer (score 0):

**elementCountAtLeast** is a lower bound so making only one pane is a valid option for a runner to do.

You have a couple of options when doing this for a batch pipeline:

1. Allow the runner to decide how big the files are and how many shards are written:

```
val pipe = sc.jdbcSelect(getReadOptions(connOptions, stmt))
        .applyTransform(ParDo.of(new Translator()))
        .map(row => row.mkString("|"))

      val out = TextIO
        .write()
        .to("gs://test-bucket/staging")
        .withSuffix(".txt")
      pipe.saveAsCustomOutput("writer",out)
```

This is typically the fastest option when the **TextIO** has a **GroupByKey** or a source that supports splitting that precedes it. To my knowledge JDBC doesn't support splitting so your best option is to add a [Reshuffle](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.17.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.html) after the **jdbcSelect** which will enable parallelization of processing after reading the data from the database.

2. Manually group into batches using the [GroupIntoBatches](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.17.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupIntoBatches.html) transform.

```
val pipe = sc.jdbcSelect(getReadOptions(connOptions, stmt))
        .applyTransform(ParDo.of(new Translator()))
        .map(row => row.mkString("|"))
        .apply(GroupIntoBatches.ofSize(500))

      val out = TextIO
        .write()
        .to("gs://test-bucket/staging")
        .withSuffix(".txt")
        .withNumShards(1)
      pipe.saveAsCustomOutput("writer",out)
```

In general, this will be slower then option #1 but it does allow you to choose how many records are written per file.

There are a few other ways to do this with their pros and cons but the above two are likely the closest to what you want. If you add more details to your question, I may revise this question further.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I've made an attempt at approach 1 which is basically what I originally started with, but with the addition of the reshuffle.  The pipeline still waits for the `jdbcSelect` to complete before doing anything.  Watching it in cloud console, you can see the downstream boxes are started until the very end.  As a result, when I run queries with large result sets, it fails with out of memory errors.

Comment: The issue must be with jdbcSelect storing too much stuff in memory as the Reshuffle doesn't actually store anything in the workers memory as the data is sent to a shuffler. The default is to load 50000 rows into memory at a time (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2cba315e10b87a6c1f8c14852299a2e0d7fc3833/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java#L229).

Comment: I've already tried setting the fetch size to 1000.  That only affects the JDBC driver.

Comment: Have you done any profiling to see where all the memory is going to?